# Java 7 Bug: Displaying Telugu through Unicode literals

Tags: unicode, rendering, java-7, unicode-literals

While displaying Telugu through unicode in Java 7,java is rendering the blends incorrectly.

For example, here is a simple snippet to display a word in HTML. It works great. All the browsers display the text correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> &#x0C05&#x0C2E&#x0C4D&#x0C2E </body>
</html>
```

However, the same literals when used in Java (here i am setting the same text to a text area, the display gets messed up.

```
    Font text_font = new Font ("Gautami", Font.PLAIN, 30);
jtaInput.setFont(text_font);
jtaInput.setText("\u0C05\u0C2E\u0C4D\u0C2E");
```

Has any one facing issues with Java 7 in the context of unicode character rendering? Any tips/ideas to get over this?

thanks
siva jasthi

Comment: అమ్మ - is rendered by HTML (that is correct) and అమమ్ will be displayed by JAVA (incorrect). I am just showing an example here. The same rendering problem happening for all consonant blends. For example, అక్క,  రాష్ట్రము etc. can not be rendered in java

Comment: Does it still work in html if you do `<body style="font-family: Gautami;">&#x0C05&#x0C2E&#x0C4D&#x0C2E </body>` ? It is then a problem with the swing renderer probably.

Comment: Yes. It still works in html even if i explicitly specify the font name there.  It appears that there is bug in java 7 rendering. And it is a devastating bug... any telugu application you develop in java 7 may become useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try using different fonts; The font that worked in Java 5 and Java 6 stopped working in Java 7. When I moved to a new Font, the display came back correctly.